# series convergence with comparison test $\frac{1}{n\log(n)^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I came across a question about convergence tests and I'm not sure how to show that

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \log(n)^p}$

converges for $p>1$. I found that the integral test works but I haven't learnt it yet. I have learnt the comparison test, so I tried that but couldn't find any series that converges to which I can compare.
So my question is both how can I show convergence here with comparison test and also: Is there some list of convergent series that I can compare to?

PS: I also found out that this is called a `ln series`
Also, this is not a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490418/series-comparison-test-for-1-nplogn) question. (The power is on the $\log$ here)

Comment: It is also a specific case of *Bertrand series*.

Comment: You could apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test, which isn't very hard to prove.

Comment: @ClementC. really? never heard of it. I'll search now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad this helped :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n)

Comment: See also: [Convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2377241) and [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9911)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HINT**   Use the Cauchy Condensation Test:
$\sum a_n$ converge iff $\sum 2^na_{2n}$ converge.

So $\sum \frac{1}{n \log(n)^p}$ converge iff $\sum 2^n\frac{1}{2^n \log(2^n)^p}$ converge.

While $\sum 2^n\frac{1}{2^n \log(2^n)^p}=\sum \frac{1}{(n\log 2)^p}=\frac{1}{(\log 2)^p}\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$

Answer (score 6):

$$
\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{1}{n\log^p n}\sim \int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log^p x}\mathrm{d}x <\infty,
$$
where the last $<$ is motivated by the fact that a primitive is $\frac{1}{\log^{p-1} x}$ (and $p-1>0$).

Comment: As I've said, I haven't learnt the integral test, and I am trying the comparison test.

Comment: You can see it as a comparison test, since the LHS is smaller than the integral, up to constants.