# Convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^c}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

> What are the values of the positive constant, $c$, for which 
>   $$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^c}$$
>   is convergent or divergent?

I am a bit confused here, because usually the $c$ value is given, so I am not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: See also: [series convergence with comparison test $\frac{1}{n\log(n)^p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2069399) and [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9911)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the integral test, for a set $a$, we see
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x\log(x)^{c}}dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log(b)^{1-c}}{1-c}-\frac{\log(a)^{1-c}}{1-c}\right)$$
which goes to infinity if $c\leq 1$ and converges if $c>1$. Thus,
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log(n)^c}$$
converges if and only if $c>1$. I discarded $n=1$ since $1*\log(1)^c=0$ which introduces dividing by $0$.

Comment: You should be consistent between $\ln$ and $\log$ and use a backslash to get the right font (i.e. `\log` instead of `log`).

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

First, comparison to $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln n}$ tells you that the series diverges if $c \le 1$. With $c > 1$, check that you can apply [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). The test gives you

$$ \frac{2^n}{2^n (\ln 2^n)^c} = \frac{1}{n^c (\ln 2)^c}, $$

which compares nicely with a $p$-series.